# Error when i try to docker-compose my .sql file from docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

i'm new with docker and i'm trying to docker-compose up my sql file but when im running it it give me this error

```
Step 2/4 : COPY setup.sh /mysql/setup.sh
ERROR: Service 'mysql' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder943384200/setup.sh: no such file or directory
```

So this is my docker-compose side

```
services: 

mysql:
    build: './db'
    container_name: mysql-container
    stdin_open: true
```

and this is my dockerfile from my mysql

```
FROM mysql:5.6

COPY setup.sh /mysql/setup.sh
COPY setup.sql /mysql/db1.sql

RUN /mysql/setup.sh
```

that im trying to run my script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
service mysql start
mysql < /mysql/db1.sql
service mysql stop
```

could someone help resolve this problem

Comment: seems like a problem with context, without knowing the complete file layout it's hard to say the exact problem. Try adding a [context attribute](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#context) . You can also try using a full path instead of relative to confirm if that's the issue.

Comment: This specific issue aside, you can't create a database image with prepopulated data.  But if you put your SQL script in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`, it will get run automatically the first time the container starts up (without needing a wrapper shell script like you've shown).